# VLookup table array from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Ive a sheet in which a cell value to be dynamically changed based on the cell value in the same row. So we have to pick that cell value first and then use that value to search in another sheet. Here is the code I have got. The sheet I have to search is **Mapper**

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("P2").Select
 formularwcount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-11], Mapper!C[-13]:C[2],3,FALSE)"
```

In this code they are using R1C1 convention which I didnt understand what they mean by putting **Mapper!C[-13]:C[2]** there as the table array. Im only a 10 days old developer with VBA. Anyone please tell what does that mean.

Comment: ‘Mapper!’ Means From worksheet Mapper

Comment: I could help if you can give examples of what you have and what you're trying to do.  Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Sorry my question is what is that Range there from the Mapper sheet c[-13]:C[2]

Comment: @ppz ThatsI think  I know , But I didnt understand that range definition there..

Comment: You better use `INDEX` + `MATCH` combination than `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this information by Googling "R1C1":

## Cell References

In place of a named cell, an alternative approach is to use a **cell** (or **grid**) **reference**. Most cell references indicate another cell in the same spreadsheet, but a cell reference can also refer to a cell in a different sheet within the same spreadsheet, or (depending on the implementation) to a cell in another spreadsheet entirely, or to a value from a remote application.

A typical **cell reference** in "**A1**" style consists of one or two case-insensitive letters to identify the column (if there are up to `256` columns: `A–Z` and `AA–IV`) followed by a row number (e.g., in the range `1–65536`). Either part can be relative (it changes when the formula it is in is moved or copied), or absolute (indicated with `$` in front of the part concerned of the cell reference).

The alternative "**R1C1**" reference style consists of ***the letter `R`, the row number, the letter `C`, and the column number; relative row or column numbers are indicated by enclosing the number in square brackets.*** Most current spreadsheets use the **A1** style, some providing the **R1C1** style as a *compatibility* option.

### Source: *[Wikipedia: Spreadsheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet)*

Comment: @Jeeped — *Uhhh, should it?  ...or are you being facetious again?!*  I've never looked into what qualifies a wiki answer but I'm [reading about it now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).  It wasn't written by me (I've never had a need to *use* R1C1 so wasn't sure what the difference was... but it took 10 seconds to figure it out.)  I'll check the "wiki" box if you think I should (and probably earn a badge for doing so!) but I'll also expand on the answer considerably.  *Your call, Mr. 4x4Coder.*

Comment: Okay I thought about it...  I think you're just messing with me... besides, I'd imagine the question will get closed sooner or later, and I assume the answers go with it, wiki or not.